# C# FtpWebRequest - Hangs when finished

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

NET Framework 4.6

I got a weird and difficult bug inside my code. When i upload a ZIP file; 150MB (slow internet, takes 15 minuten to upload) sometimes the task doesn't 100% complete. It will never get to the last Console line and hangs on the progressbar while loop.

The file on the FTP server is complete and not corrupted. So why does it hang on some files (5 out of the 10 times)?

Tried some posts from other old posts saying that it could be the request config. Also tried to close the ftpStream/fileStream after the while loop. But this won't have any effect.

Hope someone could help me out. This is the Task:

```
Task TaskA = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // Get filesize
    double len = new FileInfo(zipPathFull).Length;
    string resultSize = ConvertToReadable(len);
    ThreadSafeUpdateStatus(String.Format("Zip bestand aangemaakt, uploaden {0}...", resultSize));

    // Verstuur ZIP over FTP
    Console.WriteLine("Starting FTP commands...");
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://DOMAIN.nl/domains/DOMAIN.nl/public_html/transfer/zips/" + zipfilename + ".zip");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    request.Timeout = -1;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1000;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    Console.WriteLine("Uploading over FTP...");

    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(zipPathFull))
    using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        int read; 
        while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer status: " + (int)fileStream.Position);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

            var percent = 100m * ((decimal)fileStream.Position / fileStream.Length);
            double doublepercentage = (double)percent;
            ThreadSafeUpdateProgress(doublepercentage);

            string CurrentresultSize = ConvertToReadable((double)fileStream.Position);
            ThreadSafeUpdateStatus(String.Format("Zip bestand aangemaakt, uploaden {0}/{1}...", CurrentresultSize, resultSize));
        }

        ftpStream.Close();
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    request.Abort();

    Console.WriteLine("FTP Done");

    .....
 });
```

Comment: The fact that it works some of the time and not others leads me to believe it is network-related. Have you tried using another internet connection? Perhaps change from WiFi to wired. Or perhaps the FTP server you're using isn't that great.

Comment: hi @Adosi thanks for the quick response. I think that would be the case when the file on the FTP file is partially uploaded. But it is completed and works. Do you think it has something to do with the while loop? Not able to break out for instance? I am not a C# expert that's for sure

Comment: I would add a `Stopwatch` and make an if statement inside the loop that says "if its been greater than 30 seconds in this iteration of the loop..." then inside that if block put a breakpoint. That way once it hangs you can see if its actually stopping inside the loop and prove your theory, or if its hanging on the `.Close()` or maybe its the `ThreadSafeUpdateStatus`.

Comment: Thanks! That is some great advice. I would try that. Unfortunately it takes me a while to reproduce the bug so i will get back to you soon. Thanks again.

Comment: Yup. Basically at top of the loop do `Stopwatch ws = new Stopwatch(); ws.Start();` then at the bottom check `ws.ElapsedTime` to see if its over a certain threshold, with a breakpoint if it is. Good luck!